# facebook insights do not match with the graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to replicate the facebook insights page,(on my website) using graph api.

The problem is that the metrics I get using graph api do not **match** with the ones displayed on facebook website(picture1) for the same period of time.

[image]

Let's take for example 1.reach and 2.engagement, as it is shown in the picture, facebook showsthat I have 2328 Post reach, and 516 Post engagement for the period: 16-22 May

I tried to get the same numbers using graph api so:
1. for reach I used (page_impressions_unique) metric
2. for engagement I used (page_engaged_users) metric

As I said I get wrong numbers, so I'm thinking that maybe facebook is using another metrics than I do.

Can you please help me to get the same values for reach and engagement as the ones displayed on the facebook page?

Thanks

Comment: did you get anything on this. I am facing same issue.

Comment: unfortunately not...

Answer (score 1):

If you are in any of the US timezones, try moving your date range back a day in Facebook Insights. We had the same problem because the API pulls in GMT.